# Is there a way to add a css-class to a leaflet element?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I very much like the much cleaner dom-output of leaflet compared with google maps, but I wonder if there is a way to add a css class to markers, layers or polylines.

It would be great if something like this would be possible:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: addClass
  });
}

function addClass(e){
    layer = e.target;
    layer.addClass('soo-wonderful');
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a leaflet output for us to manipulate? Some of us may be able to help but are unfamiliar with leaflet. Also, you should probably add the `css` tag (:

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Thanks for the feedback. I suppose that someone would have to be familiar with leaflet at least a little to help, as it is redrawing the elements on every tile change, so working around this could be tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for layers there is:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: addClass
  });
}

function addClass(e){
    layer = e.target;
    var container = layer._container;
    $(container).attr('class', 'test');
}
```

Haven't tested all different cases yet, but its a good starting point.